# FB Page Login - The blue "Continue" button is off the screen (photo attached)

Tags: facebook

[image]

FB Page Login - The blue "Continue" button is off the screen

1. Facebook Login
2. Connect to business page
3. Select specific page to connect to
4. The blue "Continue" button is off the screen

What should we do? Multiple users affected by this. Photo attached.

Comment: _"Multiple users affected by this"_ - affected by what, exactly - an inability to use a scrollbar ...?

Comment: There should be a blue continue button at the bottom of the modal. It is not there, even after scrolling all the way to the bottom.

Comment: Works fine for me, when I trigger the permission dialog from within Graph API Explorer. Can't tell why it is only occupying so little of the available screen space in your screenshot there though, that might depend on the specific display parameter you call the login dialog with.